# Excel 2015 auto increment the cell reference by 5

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I have data in an Excel worksheet called "Data Sheet" in the below format.

```
F7:  ID1
F8:  Amt1
F9:  Units1
F10: Status1
F11: <blank>
F12: ID2
F13: Amt2
F14: Units2
F15: Status2
F16: <blank>
F17: ID3
F18: Amt3
F19: Units3
F20: Status3
F21: <blank>
       ⋮
```

I want to obtain the below details in another sheet ("Result Sheet"):

```
E12:    =Data Sheet'!F7
E13:    =Data Sheet'!F12
E14:    =Data Sheet'!F17
               ⋮
```

How can I make the reference to auto increment by custom multiples instead of the default increment by 1? Here I need the reference cell to be incremented by 5 while dragging the formula.

The answer in the "how to customize autofill in excel2010" thread is referring to the same sheet. But, here my requirement is referring to different work sheet. I tried modifying the  formula in the other thread, but it didn't helped me.

Comment: The answer in the "http://superuser.com/questions/927909/how-to-customize-autofill-in-excel2010" thread is referring to the same sheet. But, here my requirement is referring to different work sheet. I tried modifying the formula in the other thread, but it didn't helped me.

Answer (score 0):

E12 `=INDIRECT(CONCATENATE("'Data Sheet","'!F",7+5*(ROW()-12)))` and drag it down 
NB: the starting formula should be in E12 that is why I wrote Row()-12 if it starts in another row write the number of the row instead of 12

Answer (score 0):

The direct adaptation of my answer
to [How to customize auto fill in Excel 2010](https://superuser.com/q/927909/150988) to this problem
is to put

```
=OFFSET('Data Sheet'!$F$7, 5*(ROW()-12), 0)
```

into `'Result Sheet'!E12`, and drag/fill down.