# Get the references from the cells that are not blank

Tags: microsoft-excel, worksheet-function

I need help with a function.
In Column A I have a list of names , but they are separated with blank cells. Is there any way to show these names in Column B but without the blank cells?

The result should look like this:

[image]

Comment: @Bandersnatch: Thanks for contributing your efforts to improve the site, but — did you download the image and re-upload it?  That's sort-of a waste of resources.  All you need to do is edit the Markdown; add the `!` and the square brackets.

Comment: Simona: Are the good, non-blank data always every other row (i.e., every 2nd row)? or are they scattered randomly?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [how to customize autofill in excel2010](https://superuser.com/questions/927909/how-to-customize-autofill-in-excel2010)

Comment: @Scott, thanks.  I'll pay more attention in the future.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following array formulae will work even if any of the names are identical. Enter them in `B2` with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>, then fill down.

This one uses a fixed range based on your sample data:

```
{=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(A$1:A$10<>"",ROW(A$1:A$10),""),ROW()-ROW(A$1)+1)),"")}
```

This one uses a dynamic range, automatically adjusting as you add more names to column `A:A`:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(IF(A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*",A:A,-1))<>"",ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*",A:A,-1))),""),ROW()-ROW(A$1)+1)),"")
```

The same dynamic formula as above in an expanded form:

```
=
IFERROR(
  INDEX(
    A:A
  , SMALL(
      IF(
        A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*",A:A,-1))<>""
      , ROW(A$1:INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*",A:A,-1)))
      , ""
      )
    , ROW()-ROW(A$1)+1
    )
  )
, ""
)
```

As you can see, this second formula is simply the first one with all the `A$10` replaced with `INDEX(A:A,MATCH("*",A:A,-1))`.

**Explanation:**

The `IF()` function is equivalent to:

```
IF(
  {"";"Camilo Georgi";"";"Carla Suarez Navarro";"";"Belinda Bencic";"";"Grace Min";"";"Johanna Larsson"}<>""
, {1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10}
, ""
)
```

which, since Excel auto-expands constants into matching length constant arrays, becomes:

```
IF(
  {FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE;FALSE;TRUE}
, {1;2;3;4;5;6;7;8;9;10}
, {"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";"";""}
)
```

which evaluates to:

```
{"";2;"";4;"";6;"";8;"";10}
```

The `SMALL()` function then becomes:

```
SMALL({"";2;"";4;"";6;"";8;"";10},ROW()-1+1)
```

and since `SMALL()` ignores strings, this is equivalent to:

```
SMALL({2;4;6;8;10},ROW())
```

Note that the numbers are the indexes of the non-blank names. For cell `B1` `SMALL()` returns `2`, for `B2` it returns 4, etc. . For `B6` and lower it returns the `#NUM!` error. (This is why there is an `IFERROR()` function. It converts these errors to blanks.)

Finally, the `INDEX()` function pulls the names using the indexes.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one way to list values while excluding blank cells.  See [this help page](https://www.ablebits.com/office-addins-blog/2016/04/21/get-list-unique-values-excel/#extract-distinct-ignore-blanks) for more details.

The formula to do this requires a row above the first data row.  The headings serve that purpose in the table below.

[image]

This array formula is entered in B2:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($A$2:$A$10,MATCH(0,COUNTIF($B$1:B1,$A$2:$A$10&"")+IF($A$2:$A$10=",1,0),0)),"")
```

As an array formula, it must be entered with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>, rather than just <kbd>Enter</kbd>.  If entered correctly, Excel will surround the formula with curly brackets {} in the formula bar.

After the formula is entered, click cell B2 and fill the formula down.

In case there are duplicate names that need to be listed, this array formula will only remove blanks and not remove duplicates:

```
=IFERROR(INDEX(A:A,SMALL(INDEX(NOT(ISBLANK($A$2:$A$10))*ROW($A$2:$A$10),0),COUNTBLANK($A$2:$A$10)+ROW(C1))),"")
```

Comment: While this formula *looks* like it works, it only works for ***unique*** non-blank names. All subsequent identical names are stripped out.